# Get all the rows that contains the MAX(importo) for each id_conto

Tags: mysql

Hello i have this problem : i need all the  rows that contains the max value for each id_conto , i tried this but it returns the first row that it finds not the row that contains the max value.

table looks like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx40b.png)

Itried this:

```
SELECT id, MAX(importo), data_ora, id_conto FROM movimento_bancario WHERE id_conto IN (SELECT id FROM conto_bancario WHERE id_utente = (SELECT id FROM utente WHERE codice_fiscale = "nick")) GROUP BY id_conto;
```

This returned [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDvMD.png) but is incorrect because it should return the row with id 2 and 4

Answer (score 0):

Use a window function:

```
select id, max(importo) over (partiotion by dataora, id_conto) from movimento_bancario
```